# Cannot create JavaScript breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2017

I cannot insert breakpoints into JavaScript files in visual studio 2017. Anyone else having this issue and has anyone found a solution?

edit:
The other questions were related to breakpoints not being **HIT**. I can't even insert breakpoints into JS to begin with. The option is not in the context menu in Visual Studio.

edit 2: Even if I create a brand new JS file (since this project was created in VS2015) I still can't insert a breakpoint. The option just isn't listed in the context menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Javascript BreakPoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504160/visual-studio-javascript-breakpoint)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669163/javascript-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: The other questions were related to breakpoints not being HIT. I can't even insert breakpoints into JS to begin with. The option is not in the context menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: is your js is a `.cshtml` or `.js` file?

Comment: it's a .js file

Comment: @user609926, Which VS2017 version did you use? How did you create this JS project? It would be better if you could share us the detailed steps, if possible, please also attach a screen shot about where you set the breakpoint?

Comment: I used VS2015 Enterprise to create the project and I'm opening it in VS2017 Enterprise.It works fine in all other versions of VS (2013,2015) and I can set breakpoints with no issue. When I right-click inside the JS file the context menu does not even have a breakpoint option.

Comment: @user609926 I think some of those context menu items were removed ("cleaned up") in VS2017.  What if you hit F9 or click in the editor margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test it using a simple JavaScript app in VS2015 and VS2017 Enterprise version.

It really has this menu item in VS2015, but not in VS2017:

VS2015:
[image]

VS2017:
[image]

One workaround is that just as Jimmy's suggestion, use the F9 or add it in A with mouse in above screen shot.

Other community members also submitted this feedback to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25474/right-click-add-breakpoint-option-not-in-list.html

Comment: The option to add "insert breakpoint" isn't available through customization.  Microsoft: king of unnecessary changes.

Comment: it makes it impossible to debug js code which is minified.

Comment: @Xiaojun - Isn't it always impossible to debug minified js? ><